# Camel Exec Component Not Running Executables

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to run an example from the Apache Camel Exec Component page: http://camel.apache.org/exec.html

My Camel route builds but the command line doesn't execute. I also can't seem to get Exec to run any other executables. Any help would be much appreciated. Below is my code.

```
package demo;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;


import java.io.InputStream;

/**
 * A Camel Java DSL Router
 */
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("direct:exec").to("exec:cmd?args=/C echo %PATH%");
}
});
        context.start();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        context.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you start this direct route?

Comment: I've just been trying to run the main method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noone is calling the route.
Maybe you should use the timer component instead of the direct component(see http://camel.apache.org/timer.html) to run your example.